# Unable to read value from json file using UFT

Tags: json, vbscript, hp-uft, uft-api

I have a JSON file saved in a location, example -> `C:\Users\Desktop\test.json`

The contents of file are below;

```json
{
"users":[{
      "username":"123"
       },
    {
      "username":"456"
         }
   ]
}
```

when I try to read this file using UFT (using the below code)

```vb
Set Dom = jsonutil.Parse("C:\Users\Desktop\test.json")
```

I am getting the error "Directory not found or Json format is invalid."

How do I read the contents of JSON file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON file using VBScript - QTP/UFT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59989623/692942)